# how to queue incoming downloads and schedule them by priority?

Tags: linux, download

In a office network, how to queue incoming downloads and later, it will be scheduled by priority?

Is there any such open source project /tool available?

I have heard about squid proxy, but does it allow re scheduling ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be looking at a symptom here instead of a problem.

Would the issue be efficient use of bandwidth, which would be a matter handled well by using QoS for traffic shaping? Or is there another specific problem that can not be handled with QoS?